# readFile function without fclose

Tags: c, readfile

I have a function to add new words to a .txt file. I still have to make a function to learn the vocabulary. Several times I have to read the file, so I try to make a function for it.

```
void readFile(FILE* fp, char *name){
  if((fp=fopen(name,"a"))==NULL) {
    printf("I cannot open file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}
```

And I don't want to close the file in this function, because in other functions I would operate on this file.

```
int main(){
  FILE *file;
  readFile(file,"verbs.txt");
  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}
```

If I try to close file like that, I get core dump. But if fclose is in a readFile it works well. So it is possible to write readFile function without fclose()?

Comment: Read and close it again in another function.

Comment: `if((fp=fopen(name,"a"))=NULL)` or `if((fp=fopen(name,"a")) == NULL)`? is it a typo or a real issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All parameters in C are pass by value.  Changing the value of `fp` in your function does not change the value in the calling function.

You can return the value and use that instead:

```
FILE *readFile(char *name){
  FILE *fp;
  if((fp=fopen(name,"a"))==NULL) {
    printf("I cannot open file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return fp;
}

int main(){
  FILE *file = readFile("verbs.txt");
  fclose(file);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
void readFile(FILE** fp, char *name){
  if((*fp=fopen(name,"a"))==NULL) {
    printf("I cannot open file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main(){
  FILE *file=NULL;
  readFile(&file,"verbs.txt");
  //Use the file here after checking for NULL. 
  if (file != NULL)
      fclose(file); //check for NULL before closing.

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this would work, I think it unnecessarily complicates a function that could otherwise eliminate a parameter and instead return a useful value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `readFile` function to manage its own file pointer, I would do it more like this:

```
static FILE *fp = NULL;

void readFile(char *name){
  if((fp=fopen(name,"a"))==NULL) {
    printf("I cannot open file!\n");
    exit(1);
  }
}

void closeFile(){
  if(fp!=NULL) {
    fclose(fp);
    fp = NULL;
  }
}
```